# How to avoid text go below the icon with css?

Tags: html, css, icons, css-float, text-alignment

Here is a visual example of what I am trying to achieve with CSS:

[image]

Also live example at http://jsfiddle.net/En4yC/3/

The problem is that I need the text to be aligned next to an icon but without giving it a strict width because the container column is liquid. Do you think this is possible? Maybe some negative margin would work with floating?

```
//CSS
.column {
    width:33.3333%;
}

.ico {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right:10px;
    line-height: 32px;
    background-image: url("http://fakeimg.pl/32x32/");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

//HTML
<div class="column"> 
    <span class="ico"></span>
    <span class="title">Curabitur pharetra<br/> nibh eget<br/> lorem<br/> egestas laoreet</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.title { display: block; overflow: hidden; }
```

This way the text will be next to the image if there is an image, and if there isn't it will stick to the container's left border. I removed the br tags to show that it works without them too :

http://jsfiddle.net/En4yC/9/

Comment: This is also so awesome solution!!! I dont know which one to choose @cimmanon or yours.

Comment: Mine does not require the icon to be static size. Just saying. :D

Answer (score 2):

Make the title float next to the floating icon:

```
.title { float: left; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/En4yC/4/

Answer (score 1):

As long as your icon is a static size, you can use margins:

http://jsfiddle.net/En4yC/7/

```
.title {
    margin-left: 42px; /* size of image + desired padding after image */
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is perfect! Works even without <br> tags inside text.

Answer (score 1):

Here it goes...

**HTML**

```
<div class="column"> 
    <div class="ico"></div>
    <span class="title">Curabitur pharetra<br/> nibh eget<br/> lorem<br/> egestas laoreet</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.column
{
    width:33%;
}

.ico, 
.title
{
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:top;
}

.ico 
{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background: url("http://fakeimg.pl/32x32/") no-repeat 0px 0px;  
    padding:5px;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML:

```
<div class="content">
<img src="img.jpg" width="30" height="30" />
<p>Curabitur pharetra nibh eget lorem egestas laoreet</p>
</div>
```

And your css:

```
.content {
padding: 0 0 0 50px;
position: relative; 
}

.content img {
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hows this? This shows how you can put the icon or image in a div and place it beside another div with the text inside, this will ensure the text flows consistently.

http://jsfiddle.net/En4yC/6/

```
<div class="icon">
    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/32x32/" />
</div>
<div class="text">
    Curabitur pharetra nibh eget lorem egestas laoreet
</div>

.icon {
    float:left;
}

.text {
    float:left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the title cant have a width due to responsive design.

Comment: your text jumps below the image instead of stacking beside it